# Eigenvalue, linear mapping, matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppost that $A=(\vec v_1 \dots \vec v_n)$ is a basis for a vector space $V$ over $F$ and that the \vec v_i are eigenvectors for a linear mapping $T:V-> V$ Meaning that for each 1<=i<= $n$ there exists lamda in F such that $T(\vec v_i) = lamda_i\vec v_i $ 
What is the matrix representing $T$ with respect to $A$.

I revised what eigenvectors etc were but I feel almost like this is part of the definition. Either T is Any matrix, its A, it is some diagonal matrix (which was implied on some reading I did) or it is the eigenspace.

Sorry about some of the Latex, I'm new at it and Meta was down for maintenance so I couldnt read the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

If $v_i$ are a basis, that means every $v \in V$ can be written as $v= \sum_i x_i v_i$, for some scalars $x_i$.

Since the $v_i$ also happen to be eigenvectors of $T$, we have $Tv = T(\sum_i x_i v_i) = \sum_i x_i T v_i =\sum_i x_i\lambda_i v_i $.

So, if the representation of $v$ in the basis $v_1,...,v_n$ is $(x_1,...,x_n)$, then the representation of $Tv$ in the basis $v_1,...,v_n$ is $(\lambda_1 x_1,...,\lambda_n x_n)$.

Then the matrix you want is the matrix that takes $(x_1,...,x_n)$ to $(\lambda_1 x_1,...,\lambda_n x_n)$.

Comment: which would be λI?

Comment: Well, it would be something like $\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & 0& \cdots \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 & \cdots \\ 
\cdots & 0 & \lambda_3  \\ & & & \ddots& \\ & & & &\lambda_n\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: ah I see. which is best described as the matrix of zeros with the eigenvalues as the leading diagonal?

Comment: Yup. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: For any integer $1\le k\le n,$ we can uniquely express $T(\vec v_k)=\sum_{j=1}^nc_{j,k}\vec v_j,$ where $$c_{j,k}=\begin{cases}\lambda_k & j=k\\0 & j\ne k.\end{cases}$$ Now, what is the $k$th column of the matrix of $T$ with respect to the ordered basis $A$, by definition?